# Problem with manual upgrade

Tags: updating, manual-updates

I tried to upgrade a website that I have to the latest version 2.6.2930 from an older 2.6.2804 and for an unknown reason the upgrade failed. I couldn't log in the administration area but the front end was working.

Now I tried to roll back to an old backup that I had 20 days ago. So I restored mysql database askitis.gr_160813_184933_v2.6.2804.sql and I uploaded only the folder /craft/app from the older version of craft Craft-2.6.2804

Now when I get to the website administration panel I get the button to finish up the installation like I'm updating the website. Any ideas what's going on? According to everything I read in order to roll back you need the db and files to be of the same version. I check the craft_info and this is the case

Answer (score 2):

Delete your `craft/storage/runtime/cache` and `craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates` folder after doing this manual update.

Otherwise Craft still references the (now renamed) Garnish Javascript, and the UI for the AdminCP is not functional.

Comment: Probably that was the problem because the java scrips and the graphic interface wasn't working although i tried to clear the cache of the browser. But now I got another problem... I'm not getting /admin/ screen to load and I get HTTP ERROR 500 with devmode this: Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimeFormat() on null in /home/askitis/craft/app/etc/requirements/RequirementsChecker.php on line 103

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem.

I had 2 custom locales and when I uploaded the new files for the manual update and I didn’t include those 2 locales.

When I copied those 2 files in the folder app/framework/i18n/data everything worked.